# Query about MVC Controls Toolkit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, controls, codeplex

I have seen [mvccontrolstoolkit](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/)  new upcoming controls for ASP.MVC. In the project description it is written that these are advanced **Server Controls**. Are these controls are like webfrom server controls. Do these controls voilate MVC design pattern?. I have a concern about the **Server Control** keyword in their description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MVC Controls toolkit page](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/)

> Enabling MVC programmers to implements rich user interfaces without renouncing to the separation of concerns between the View Model that defines just What data to display and the View that defines How to display those data

So I would say no, the controls don't violate the MVC design pattern.

By 'server controls' they are referring to HTML helpers and model binders that execute on the server.